# If part of an infinite series diverges, does the whole series diverge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

If you can write some infinite series $S_1$ as the sum $S_2+S_3$, is it always the case if atleast one of $S_2, S_3$ diverges that $S_1$ diverges?

Comment: Think about [the alternating harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#Alternating_harmonic_series) (and more generally, the notion of *conditional convergence*).

Answer (score 0):

If only one of $S_2$ or $S_3$ converges, then $S_1$ diverges. However, if both $S_2$ and $S_3$ diverge, it depends on what you are looking at. I think, in retrospect, it is "likely" to diverge, but in some cases, for example where $S_2$ and $S_3$ are symmetrical, i.e. cancel out each other in some sense, then it does not. So before we actually compute it, we cannot tell anything about convergence if both diverge.